# Difference between expect_fatal_failure & plain assertion

Tags: c++, googletest

First, I'm so sorry for my bad English.

In github of Google Test, it explains expect_fatal_failure assertions this way :

> EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE(statement, substring); to assert that statement
>   generates a fatal (e.g. ASSERT_*) failure whose message contains the
>   given substring

But when I ran my project of expect_fatal_failure, I couldn't find difference between executing statement with EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE(statement, substring) & just executing statement

here is my code,

```
#include "gtest/gtest.h"
#include "gtest/gtest-spi.h"

void failTwice()
{
   EXPECT_TRUE(false) << "fail first time";
   ASSERT_TRUE(false) << "fail second time";
}

TEST(FailureTest, FirstTest)
{
   EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE(failTwice(), "time");
   failTwice();
}

TEST(FailureTest, SecondTest)
{
   EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE(failTwice(), "second");
   failTwice();
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    testing::InitGoogleTest(&argc, argv);
    return RUN_ALL_TESTS();
}
```

and result is in image.

[image: result]

Is there anything wrong the way I did?

or there aren't any difference between them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The output basically is telling you what is happening: the `EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE` statement tells Google Test to expect one failure in the invocation of `FailTwice` but it produces two. Comment the second line in that function and remove extra calls to `FailTwice` and both tests will pass, e.g.

```
void failNonFatallyOnFalse(bool param)
{
   EXPECT_TRUE(param) << "fail non-fatally";
}

void failFatallyOnFalse(bool param)
{
   ASSERT_TRUE(param) << "fail fatally";
}

TEST(FailureTest, TestFailNonFatally)
{
   EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE(failNonFatallyOnFalse(false), "fail non-fatally");
}

TEST(FailureTest, TestFailFatally)
{
   EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE(failFatallyOnFalse(false), "fail fatally");
}
```

You can think of them as turning failure into success and success into failure.

This doesn't seem very useful at the first glance, but the documentation [explains](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/35fb11efbe1a2761ce923f49a9df1a430e5d16be/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#catching-failures) what these macros are for: they are useful if you are building your own assertions, for example using [predicate formatters](https://github.com/google/googletest/blob/35fb11efbe1a2761ce923f49a9df1a430e5d16be/googletest/docs/AdvancedGuide.md#using-a-predicate-formatter). You write your assertion and run it under `EXPECT_NONFATAL_FAILURE` or `EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE` with different parameters and verify that it produces a failure with the expected output. If you are just using Google Test to write regular tests, you don't need these two assertions.

Comment: ohhh... It seems i didn't see carefully results. so then it can tell me about presence of "a" failure including substring, right?

Comment: You can make an assertion about exactly one failure being present and having a particular substring in its message. So that would be "the" failure, I guess.

Answer (score 0):

This is the solution we came up with. [I would mark as duplicate to point to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24037390/how-can-i-expect-multiple-failures-in-google-test/68331825), but I lack the reputation.:

```
//adapted from EXPECT_FATAL_FAILURE
do {
  //capture all expect failures in test result array
  ::testing::TestPartResultArray gtest_failures;
  //run method in its own scope
  ::testing::ScopedFakeTestPartResultReporter gtest_reporter(
    ::testing::ScopedFakeTestPartResultReporter::
    INTERCEPT_ONLY_CURRENT_THREAD, &gtest_failures);
  //run your method
  failTwice();
  //only check on number, this will include fatal and nonfatal, but if you just care about number then this is sufficient
  ASSERT_EQ(gtest_failures.size(), 2) << "Comparison did not fail FATAL/NONFATAL twice";
} while (::testing::internal::AlwaysFalse());
```